# Testing internal classes when using test class inheritance

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mstest

I cannot build the test project beacuse I get: *Inconsistent accessibility: property type 'Lib.MyClass' is less accessible than property 'Lib.Tests.GivenMyClass.Cut'*.

**Assembly Lib**

```
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo(".Lib.Tests")]

internal class MyClass
{
    public string Foo(int x) { ... }
}
```

**Assembly Lib.Test**

```
public GivenMyClass
{
    protected internal SynchronizedDataLink Cut { get; private set; } // Inconsistent accessibility: property type 'Lib.MyClass' is less accessible than property 'Lib.Tests.GivenMyClass.Cut'

    public GivenMyClass()
    {
        Cut = new MyClass();
    }
}

[TestClass]
public WhenFooCalled
{
    private int x;

    public WhenFooCalled()
    {
        x = Create.Any<int>();
        Cut.Foo(x);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void ThenSomething() 
    { 
        // assert something using x 
    }
}
```

**What are the solutions - how can I make it working?**

1. I do not want to make the 'MyClass' as public because it is
   dedicated just for one assembly. This is the use-case of using internal - am I correct?
2. The real code is much more complex and thanks to the following
   pattern of writing unit tests it removes as a lot of test code
   redundancy and makes the refactoring easier. However I do not say
   that I strictly must follow this pattern of writing...

I can for example write my tests like this:

```
[TestClass]
public MyClassTests
{
    private MyClass cut;

    public MyClassTests()
    {
        cut = new MyClass();
    }

    public int ExecuteFoo()
    {
        int x = Create.Any<int>();
        cut.Foo(x);
        return x;
    }

    [Fact]
    public void Foo_ThenSomething() 
    {
        int x = ExecuteFoo();
        // assert something using x 
    }
}
```

However then I had a lot of invoking like `ExecuteFoo` and everything is in one class. Int inhertiance pattern when we change a method int the ClassUnderTest then we change only tests in one class (high cohesion). In the one-class approach everything is in one place (a lot of unreadable code)...

Comment: Why do you need `GivenMyClass.Cut` to be protected internal? Why not just make it `internal`? Alternatively, I suspect that if you change `GivenMyClass` to make the class itself `internal`, that would work too.